# Encoding in Streamreader in my silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding

Having trouble geting the encoding right in my silverlight application.
I need support for western europe letters like æ,ø,å,â and so(Latin1??).
But I can't get it right. What should be instead of SOMEENCODINGHERE? did try 
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Latin1"); but no names I used as param was recognized =( .
If I use Encoding.Unicode tr.ReadLine() reads the whole file and convert it to Chinese for some reason.

```
    private Dictionary<int, string> InitDictionary()
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var sri = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fileDic, UriKind.Relative));
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream, Encoding.SOMEENCODINGHERE))
        {
            int i = 0;
            string line;
            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                d.Add(i++, line);
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want ISO-Latin-1, you can use

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

But the normal Windows Western Europe code page is 1252:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Are you absolutely *sure* that's the encoding for your stream though? These days it's more common to use UTF-8. What's generating your text resource?

Comment: But GetEncoding want string as parameter not an integer

Comment: Well there's *an* overload that takes a string - but at least in the desktop framework, there's an overload taking an integer. Does that not exist in Silverlight? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it, The file I have is a dictionary that I download from a 3rd party provider. And do not know the Encoding of. I think I going to write someting that convert the file to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight (1-4, don't known about 5) doesn't support ANSI Encodings (codepages). It supports only Unicode encodings: UTF8 and UTF16.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28VS.95%29.aspx for details.
So suggested Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) and any other codepage numbers do *not* work.
You have to implement your Encoding class for needed codepage. 
If you have found an appropriate implementation please share it, i'd be interesting.